# Popup not hiding when opening another NSView-popup from status bar

Tags: objective-c, nsview, nswindowcontroller

I found this project which works almost perfectly as a base for what I'm trying to  do https://github.com/shpakovski/Popup. It places an icon at the menu bar which when clicked displays a popup. The popup internal NSWindow is controlled by its delegate which is called PanelController. It's delegate methods are executed most of the time as it is expected, for example, the (void)windowDidResignKey:(NSNotification *)notification is executed when I click almost anywhere. 
Though, it is not executed the **first time** I click another item of the menu bar, for example the skype item. This is what I get:

[image]

Any ideas on which NSWindow delegate method am I missing to intercept that first click on another menu bar item?

Answer (score 0):

Just opening menu doesn't make window resign key/main, and opening menu from status item works similar as opening own menu.

I could find only one case where menu can make window resign key, which is when application is not the active one (I find it a bit weird, that it's even possible). So, if your application doesn't need to have own windows, except the popup, you could make it give up focus at start using for example (or maybe even with small delay to make sure the app was deactivated and focus was given to other application):

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] hide:nil]; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it will not work as my application does have its own windows, in addition to the popup.

Comment: well, in this case I can think of proper solution - use menu with embedded object, but this might be problematic, ugly solution - call hide: and the unhideWithoutActivation if your app is open, or even worse solution - run two instances where one will be responsible for windows, and second for menu.
Also - note that if you take app using similar components (Dropbox is good example), open some window (preferences in this case) you'll have the same problem as here - popup is not closed by menus.

Comment: @Rychu, but the popup IS being closed by the menu usually. It's only the very first time when the app is launched that it doesn't work (windowDidResignKey notification never received). Once the popup is opened and you click outside of it to close it, everything starts working properly and windowDidResignKey notification is received every time you open a different app's menu.

Comment: @Danielv - that's because then the popup app is not the active one anymore. Adding a window will bring the issue back - just click at the window and then use popup.

Comment: @Rychu - not sure what you mean by "adding a window". In that popup sample application, once I click outside the popup window, I can't make the problem appear again. Also, calling [NSApp deactivate] or hiding it should have simulated the same behavior and solved the problem, but it doesn't.